# Django admin login works, but auth_views.login doesn't (no password required)

Tags: django, authentication

I've overridden my auths to allow anyone with an ldap entry to login without a password.  It works in the admin version of the login screen, but not the one based on auth_views.login (the auth_views.login one just refreshes to the same login form after submission.)

I added a debug breakpoint in my ExistsInLDAP.authenticate() method and it breaks for the django admin login, but not for my auth_views.login, so there is something wrong with my glue code/config, not the code itself... I think.

urls.py:

```
url(r'^accounts/login/$', auth_views.login, name='login'),
```

settings.py

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
        'misc.auth.ExistsInLDAP',
        'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
        )

AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = "account.UserProfile"
```

misc/auth.py:

```
class ExistsInLDAP(ModelBackend):
    """
    Django authentication plugin to just check if user is in ldap.
    """

    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        """
        Validate the user is in ldap.  Password is ignored.
        """
        [ ldap checking ....]

        user, created = User.objects.\
                          get_or_create(username=username,
                                        defaults={
                                            'first_name': r['givenName'][0],
                                            'last_name': r['sn'][0],
                                            'email': r['mail'][0],
                                            'is_superuser': True,
                                            'is_staff': True,
                                            'password': '!',
                                        })

        if created:
            user.set_unusable_password()

        return user
```

login template:

```
{% extends "base.djhtml" %}

{% block title %}Login{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <form role="form" method="post" action="{% url django.contrib.auth.views.login %}">

                {% csrf_token %}

                {% if form.errors %}
                <p class="form-error login-form-error">
                    {{ form.get_error }}
                </p>
                {% endif %}

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="{{ form.username.id }}">{{ form.username.label_tag }}:</label>
                    {{ form.username }}@vmware.com
                    <br>
                    {% comment %}XXX: group has decided passwords aren't needed.{% endcomment %}
                    <input type="text" hidden="true" value="1234567890" id="{{ form.password.id_for_label }}"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as I typed this question, I figured out the answer.  I figure I'll still post and answer it here for others.

The problem is the hidden password field:

My HTML form doesn't include all of the html labels required.  I figured this out by rendering an form.as_p version of the form and comparing.  The password field was misssing 'name':

```
<input type="password" name="password" id="id_password" />
```